# Traduction de "(may) pop into mind"

Tags: traduction, anglais, usage

> Suppose we need the formula for the area of a circle for some computation. Like many people who learned geometry too long ago to recall with any certainty, two expressions **may pop into our mind** when we think of circles: πr^2 and 2πr. One expression is the circumference of a circle of radius r and the other is its area. But which is which?
>
> Supposons que nous ayons besoin de la formule pour l'aire d'un cercle pour certains calculs. Comme beaucoup de gens qui ont appris la géométrie il y a trop longtemps à se rappeler avec certitude, deux expressions **peuvent surgir dans notre esprit** lorsque nous pensons aux cercles: πr ^ 2 et 2πr. Une formule est la circonférence d'un cercle de rayon r et l'autre est sa surface. [Mais laquelle est laquelle](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/34048/traduction-de-but-which-is-which) ?

Je me demande si *(peuvent) surgir dans notre esprit* est comprehensible en français. Vu la discussion pour [mind-esprit](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25694/mind-in-french) est-ce mieux de dire "surgir dans notre tête" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Surgir dans l'esprit* n'est pas la plus idiomatique, l'expression consacrée est *venir à l'esprit* :

> ...deux expressions peuvent nous *[venir à l'esprit](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/venir_%C3%A0_l%E2%80%99esprit)* lorsque nous...

[image]

Comment: Parfait ; donc esprit peut bien représenter mind dans ce contexte.  Merci encore une fois.

Comment: Tu es d'accord avec mon commentaire ? "Je crois que TLFi dans son zèle de présenter la beauté de la langue française donne des exemples d'usage littéraires, non courants, obsolètes voire inusités : Se présenter à l'esprit, se former dans la pensée de manière nette et précise. Une vision surgit dans l'esprit, la mémoire. Et voilà que surgit dans ma pensée un très ancien souvenir (Maupass., Contes et nouv., t. 1, Colp., 1890, p. 1167). La même image surgit dans tous les esprits: le vieux Krüger, à demi-aveugle, courant l'Europe pour quêter la pitié des nations (Tharaud, Dingley, 1906, p. 107)."

Comment: J'ai ajusté le début de ma réponse. L'expression *surgir dans l'esprit* existe bien mais est beaucoup moins courante que *venir à l'esprit*. *Surgir* est aussi un peu plus soudain et inattendu que *venir*.

Answer (score 2):

L'idée est tout à fait bonne puisqu'elle est confirmée par l'acception figurée, vérifiable dans le TLFi ;

> a) Se présenter à l'esprit, se former dans la pensée de manière nette et précise. Une vision surgit dans l'esprit, la mémoire.

On peut de plus changer légèrement l'image et dire « sauter aux yeux » ; suivent les explications de l'internaute ;

Les yeux permettent de voir une information et de la faire analyser. Ainsi lorsque quelque chose saute aux yeux, l'information est évidente et elle est comprise instantanément. L'expression désigne aussi quelque chose qui nous a échappé.

Comment: Merci bien ! Je crois que TLFi dans son zèle de présenter la beauté de la langue française donne parfois des exemples d'usage un peu vieux quand même : Se présenter à l'esprit, se former dans la pensée de manière nette et précise. Une vision surgit dans l'esprit, la mémoire. Et voilà que surgit dans ma pensée un très ancien souvenir (Maupass., Contes et nouv., t. 1, Colp., 1890, p. 1167).La même image surgit dans tous les esprits: le vieux Krüger, à demi-aveugle, courant l'Europe pour quêter la pitié des nations (Tharaud, Dingley, 1906, p. 107).

Comment: Donc, peut-être cet emploi figuré n'est pas plus courant.

Comment: Selon le livre "A French Reference Grammar, H. Ferrar, p. 202. (Oxford University Press, 2nd Edition, 1967)" le pronom y peut remplacer des choses introduites par à, en et dans. "Je n'y ai aucune confiance (avoir confiance en)." To cite @jlliagre "Cette phrase peut nous laisser perplexe. Google books n'en trouve qu'une poignée d'occurrences, souvent dans des textes traduits, et essentiellement durant une période située entre 1830 et 1940."
See the discussion here https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29587/avoir-confiance-en-p%C3%A9n%C3%A9trer-dans-plus-nom-et-le-pronom-y

Comment: Je veux dire que la langue évoluant toujours des usages, des significations, et ainsi de suite deviennent obsolètes voire inadéquats (comme race pour les hommes par exemple:-)!).

Comment: @dimitris Non, je crois que le verbe surgir est un verbe qui ne peut pas vieillir, un verbe de tous les temps ; c'est cependant d'un registre assez littéraire, mais la langue littéraire est appréciée par beaucoup de monde dans le parler courant, sauf par certains qui ont une certaine répugnance à recourir à un vocabulaire avec lequel, par manque d'habitude, il ne sont pas à l'aise et cela peut même les induire a trouver des raisons pour le rejeter; pourquoi la langue littéraire devrait-elle être une langue morte ? Qu'elle soit parlée aussi autant que possible !

Comment: @dimitris L'évolution du langage n'est pour rien dans l'éradication du mot « race »  ; c'est un fait socio-politique et un fait très regrettable selon mon point de vue. Si vous partez du point de vue que parce que certain ont rechigner à un usage vous devez aussi le faire quelque chose n'est pas normal chez vous ; vous devez être convaincu d'un point de vue objectif pour faire un tel choix. Je n'en ai pas à vous donner, ce verbe et cet usage figuré ne sont pas étranges pour moi ; je trouve l'usage que vous en avez fait même assez recherché, mais cela est mon opinion personnelle.

Comment: Merci pour ces commentaires très éclairants.

Comment: @dimitris En ce qui concerne le pronom « y » je dois dire que je crois bien qu'il y a quelque chose de réel dans ce dont vous faites part ; j'identifie bien un certain malaise dans l'utilisation de ce pronom, une incertitude quant à la netteté avec laquelle le référent est ressenti, cependant  seulement dans des cas particuliers, lesquels demandent tout une recherche personnelle si je devais approfondir la question.